# Add condition to specific content type in apache solr

Tags: views, search

I've installed [apachesolr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr),[search api solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) and views. I have only indexed article and basic page content type.

Then i've added new field "internal use only" as checkbox for article content type. I want to add filter "internal use only" only in article content type. I want to show except those articles.

How to alter apache query?

Answer (score 0):

Check [apachesolr.api](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/7) >> [hook_apachesolr_query_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_query_alter/7)

```
function hook_apachesolr_query_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  // I only want to see articles by the admin.
  //
  // NOTE: this "is_uid" filter does NOT refer to the English word "is"
  // It is a combination of flags representing Integer-Single, which is
  // abbreviated with the letters i and s.
  //
  // @see the <dynamicField> definitions in schema.xml or schema-solr3.xml
  $query->addFilter("is_uid", 1);

  // Only search titles.
  $query->replaceParam('qf', 'label');
}
```

More details about solr query [DrupalSolrQueryInterface](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21apachesolr.interface.inc/interface/DrupalSolrQueryInterface/7)

Comment: How to do this?